# Admob integration into AndEngine BaseGameActivity, alternative to SurfaceView?

Tags: android, admob, andengine

Alright. So I have been making a game app in Android using AndEngine. I've gotten to the point where I want to implement ads into the game and I've been trying to use Admob for that purpose.

Problem is however, every example and everything I've found on the internet points to using layouts for it. The game that I'm creating doesn't utilize any layouts whatsoever. It uses the Camera function to display things. I.E

```
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

    camera = new Camera(0, 0, 1024f, 1024f);
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(), this.camera);
    engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true).setNeedsSound(true);
    return engineOptions;

}
```

Is there any possible alternative, possibly using the Camera to display banner ads?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no. But still using andEngine you can use layouts to show ads. Here is my example I use in andEngine game (it is based on modified example from andEngine forum: http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/google-admob-in-andengine-tutorial-t10822.html):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);


this.adView = new AdView(this);
this.adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
this.adView.setAdUnitId("PUT YOUR NUMBER");
com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest adrequest = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().build(); //you can use test device as you did in your code


this.adView.loadAd(adrequest);

RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


layout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView);



layout.addView(this.adView, params);

}
```

This example is for smart banner ads. way to show and hide them is shown in the forum example.